# Specify different library path for different R version

Tags: r

Different versions of R have installed in the cluster. How can I set different library path for different R version?

UPDATE:
Thanks to @nicola, **.libPaths()** or **library** can set library path and help R find the specific location of packages. 
Is there any way to do this in a system wide, like some system environment value. So I can start R and find the specific location automatically.

Comment: See `?.libPaths`. Also, check the `require` and `library` `lib.loc` argument.